# What is the http url to get readiness and liveness probes of service instances from kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I searched for 'readi', 'ready', 'live' etc in the kub swagger. I only see

```
io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodReadinessGate
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

That's one thing you would define. For example the following yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    livenessProbe:       #this block performs liveness probes
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 80
    readinessProbe:      #this block performs readiness probes
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 80
```

So, a pod with nginx. I can simply add the blocks highlighted in the yaml file and there it is. kubelet will check on them. Of course you have to have something serving there (/healthz, in this example), otherwise you will get 404.

You can add some configuration to the probes, like the other answer suggests. There are some more options than those.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Configure Liveness and Readiness Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/) services can be configured to use

- `liveness command`
- `TCP liveness probe`
- `liveness HTTP request`

So if your service use HTTP requests for liveness and readiness you can see in pod definition section `livenessProbe` (same for `readinessProbe`)

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /healthz
    port: 8080
  initialDelaySeconds: 3
  periodSeconds: 3
```

See full example [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/blob/master/content/en/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/http-liveness.yaml)

Comment: these yaml snippets are showing how to setup the probes, right ? But, my need is to fetch some deployment/runtime details from k8s. for ex; in our deployment we have 3 web applications, kafka, couple of databases etc. Let us call those apps as ms-A, ms-B, ms-C. And say 2 instances of each are running.  Assuming  that liveness, readiness probes are configured, kubernetes now has that information. My question is, how do I get this info from kubernetes using the http api.

Comment: In the output of '/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/pod-1' , I see 'containerstatuses' which has the following : "ready": true,
"restartCount": 1,
"image": "",
"imageID": "",
"containerID": ""   is this the right property ? Why don't I see similar structure for 'live' ? (I see that both probes are configured in our system).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to check the state of Liveness and Readiness probes directly.
You can check the resulting state of the pod which reflects changes in the state of Liveness and Readiness probes, but with some delay caused by threshold values.
Using `kubectl describe pod` you can also see some events at the bottom, but you can only see them after they occur. You can’t have it as a reply to the request.

You can also look into REST requests that are running under the hood of kubectl commands. All you need to do is adding a verbose flag to kubectl command:

```
-v, --v=0: Set the level of log output to debug-level (0~4) or trace-level (5~10)
```

Comment: thank you. I see where the confusion is; what I want is the 'result of the probe checks'. I don't care about the probes themselves or what status they are in. I only care about what they reported to kubernetes. I saw some info in the api /pods output.